# Export graph to pdf use jquery flot

Tags: jquery, charts, flot, jspdf, html2canvas

I had a problem about export more graphs which used `jquery flot` to `pdf`

I used `html2canvas.js` and `jspdf-min.js` to export `graphs` to `pdf`, but i had two problems:

**First**, it exported to `pdf` too ugly.

**Second**, i want to export two graphs inside **one page**, but it exported to two pages.

Here my code:

```
var _canvas = null;
$(function() {
  $("#id_generate_pdf").on("click", function (e) {
    window.allcanvas = [];
    var allcontainers = $('[id^="flot-placeholder"]');

    allcontainers.each(function (index, elem) {
      html2canvas($(elem).get(0), {
        onrendered: function (canvas) {
          window.allcanvas.push(canvas);
          if(allcontainers.length == allcanvas.length){
            finalpdf();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });

  finalpdf = function(){
    var doc = new jsPDF('landscape');
    for(var i = 0; i< allcanvas.length; i++){
      var imgData = allcanvas[i].toDataURL('image/jpeg');
      doc.addImage(imgData, 'JPEG', 10, 10, 280, 65);
      if(i != allcanvas.length-1) {
        doc.addPage();
      }
    }
    doc.save('testingPDF.pdf');
  };
});
```

Here is my demo: [My demo code](http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/514/)

Hope every body can support me. Thank you very much.

**Update**:

I want to export `pdf` and this `pdf` include this text same as `image` which i attached.

I don't know how to do that. Please give me some ideas or some advises. Thank you very much.

[My demo code update](http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/516/)

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Remove the call to `doc.addPage();`
- Change the width and height in the parameters of `doc.addImage()` to something with the same ratio as your chart.
- Change the y-position for the second chart so it doesn't overlap the first.
- Set white background to the charts and the canvas.

See this updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/g2CTz/515/

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked as well. But can i ask you a question ? Or can you give me some idea how to do it ? I was updated my question.

Comment: Use the [`text()`](https://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/doc/symbols/jsPDF.html#text) function.